# Why can't I access a field defined as "Select 1" from a subquery in the outer query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-server-2014

I have this subquery:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 as exist
                  , MAX (ev.EventDate) as eventdate
                  , evt.EventCode
                  , CCaseID
           FROM stg.Event ev 
           JOIN stg.EventTemplate evt 
             ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
           WHERE evt.EventCode = 'UN002' 
           Group by CCaseID, evt.EventCode) as un002
    ON un002.CCaseID = ev.CCaseID
WHERE evt.EventCode = 'UN001' 
  AND (un002.eventdate < ev.eventdate OR un002.eventdate IS NULL)
Group by ev.CCaseID, evt.EventCode) as un001
  ON cc.ID = un001.CCaseID
```

I am now trying to access the exist field in the outer query as per `un001.exist` but SQL Server tells me that it is an invalid field. What am I missing?

Comment: If the column is called 1, just try bracketing the number [1] with square brackets as shown.

Comment: Are you asking why you can't access the column named "exist" in your main query?

Comment: Well....un001.exist is not a valid column. You named that subquery as un002. This would be easier for you to see if there was some better formatting.

Comment: I bet this is issue is at a higher level.  This looks like a mess of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`un001` doesnt have `exist` that field belong to `un002` subquery.

Also you have a `GROUP BY` and the and `ON` so there is some missing code there.

You should simplify the code and use CTE to make it easy to read and debug.

Something like this :

```
WITH un001 as ( SELECT ... ), 
un002 as ( SELECT ...)
SELECT *
FROM un001 
JOIN un002
  ON un001 .CCaseID = un002.CCaseID
```

Comment: They don't have the plural of exist in the code posted.

Comment: @SeanLange You are right I totally miss the question.